# How to set CApath for NGINX SSL Connection

Tags: ssl, nginx, openssl

I'm trying to set up an SSL connection to SagePay from my website. I can run the openssl s_client successfully, it returns: **Verify return code: 0 (ok)**, but only if I specify the CApath e.g.

```
openssl s_client -connect test.sagepay.com:443 -CApath /usr/local/ssl/certs/
```

When I try using the website I get an error:

```
OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError (SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read server certificate B: certificate verify failed):
```

How do I tell NGINX where to find the ssl certs I have installed?

Comment: This seems like an application issue - is your site running in the nginx process space, or do you use nginx as a reverse proxy to your site?

Comment: I'm using Nginx running on Passenger, the configuration is set in a Nginx configuration file and the website is written in Ruby On Rails.. I'm not sure if that's "running in the nginx process space" or as a "reverse proxy" ? How can I tell?

Comment: Is there a separate Ruby or Passenger process running when the server is up?  You can by looking at the process list using `top` on Unix-like systems (not sure about Windows).  If so, then *that* is the process you need to configure to trust the SagePay certificate.  Otherwise you might need to set some OpenSSL env vars for Nginx.